# Laptop DC voltage being changed

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power

I got Toshiba Laptop, The voltage of Charger being changed when Plugin the Power, but When I checked the charger without plugin it shows correct Dc voltage and current by Digital Multimeter. Please advice.

thanks

Comment: What are the two voltage reading?

Answer (score 2):

Power supplies can have a voltage drop when under load. Of course, a large voltage drop can mean that the charger is underrated or defective; try another charger.

Comment: Its being changed contineously, such as 1.5, 1.2 1.8 etc